# XSLT copy nodes with recursion

Tags: xml, xslt

i am new to XSLT and i have XML file with the following structure:

```
<A>
  <label>
    <c>Tag number 1</c>
  </label>
  <row>
    <c>Tag Number 2</c>
  </row>
  <label>
    <c>Tag number 3</c>
  </label>
</A>
```

and what i want is to separate the `A` tag to be like:

```
<A>
  <label>
    <c>Tag number 1</c>
  </label>
  <row>
    <c>Tag number 2</c>
  <row>
</A>
<A>
  <label>
    <c>Tag number 3</c>
  </label>
</A>
```

so what i want is to separate `A` tag depending on `label` tag, in other words, copy `label` tag and all following tags till the second `label` tag which will be separated to another `A` tag with all following tags and so on....

i hope that i described it clearly and forgive my dump question.

Thank You in advance

Comment: If you are using XSLT 2.0, then this should be trivial using `<xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="...">`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k am sorry michael i suppose to use XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a key to look up the non-label elements by their first most preceding `label` elements

```
<xsl:key name="label" match="*[not(self::label)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::label[1])" />
```

You can then start off by selecting all the `label` elements only

```
<xsl:template match="A">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="label" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then, within the template that matches `label` you can get all the associated elements by using then key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('label', generate-id())"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="label" match="*[not(self::label)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::label[1])" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="A">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="label" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="label">
      <A>
         <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('label', generate-id())"/>
      </A>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I am using the Identity Template to copy all existing nodes in the document.